# Automatic function call on instance variable of Python class?

Tags: python, function, class, variables, instance

So lets say I have a class called `Car` as below:

```
class Car(object):
    """Car example with weight and speed."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = None
        self.speed = None
```

If I initialize a `Car` as an empty object:

```
red_car = Car()
```

And I add a `speed` and a `weight`:

```
red_car.speed = 60
red_car.weight = 3500
```

That's all fine but what if I want to run a function when attempting to add those variables to the instance? Like this function:

```
def change_weight(self, any_int):
    return (any_int - 10)
```

The thing is though I want it to automatically run this function whenever I attempt to add specific instance variables to the object. If possible I would like it to run `change_weight` only on the `weight` instance variable.

Am I understanding this correctly or should I just be running the integer through the function separately and then adding to the object after manually?

Comment: This seems like a perfect use case for getters and setters.

Comment: @GWW, Noooo. This is Python not Java

Comment: @gnibbler: Sorry I should have said `properties`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use properties

```
class Car(object):
    """Car example with weight and speed."""
    def __init__(self):
        self._weight = None # internal value
        self.speed = None

    @property
    def weight(self):
        return self._weight

    @weight.setter
    def weight(self, the_weight):
        self._weight = the_weight - 10 # or whatever here
```

Now, you can set `speed` normally; when you execute `car.weight = 20` the setter function will be called, and the actual weight will be set to `20 - 10 = 10`.

Comment: All this time.. so wait a sec let me see if I understand this correctly then.. You're declaring the function called `weight` with a decorator `property` but it's returning to the instance `_weight` (why a private value? Why not just `weight`? Then you have another function called `weight` but this has a decorator called `weight.setter` on it, I assume because then when I do `car.weight = 20` it runs this function? And the decorator `weight.setter` grabs the other `weight` function as a return once the `weight.setter` function is done? For the most part it makes sense.

Comment: I just am looking for clarification that what I wrote above is correct and the whole thing about having to make it a private variable with the `_`.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on Python's notion of [Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/descriptor.html).  In particular, it sounds like you want to define a custom `__set__()` method.

> For example, `obj.d` looks up `d` in the dictionary of `obj`. If `d` defines the method`__get__()`, then `d.__get__(obj)` is invoked according to the precedence rules listed below.

Alternately, you may find using [`Properties`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/descriptor.html#properties) (a specific type of Descriptor) a little easier to work with.

> `property()` is a succinct way of building a data descriptor that triggers function calls upon access to an attribute.

The behavior of descriptors is fairly logical once you understand it, but it doesn't behave quite as you might expect; in particular, `__get__()` and `__set__()` should not be confused with getters and setters, like the Java concept.  So look at some of the examples above and play around with them before diving in.

Comment: Interesting! Will do!