# Ruby: automatically call a method when attribute is set

Tags: ruby, class, properties

I am new to Ruby, and to object oriented programming more generally.

I think what I want is exactly a Ruby translation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555295/automatic-function-call-on-instance-variable-of-python-class).  That is, I want to be able to initialize an instance of the class, and then as soon as a certain attribute is set call a method on it to convert it.

For example, say I had a Weather class with a temperature attribute that I would like converted from Fahrenheit to Celsius as soon as it is set. Here is the way I would like this to behave.

```
today = Weather.new
today.temp = 32
today.temp     # => 0
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own `attr_writer`-style method to accomplish this. Feel free to comment if this is unclear.

```
class Weather
  attr_reader :temp
  def temp=(val)
    @temp = f_to_c(val)
  end
  def f_to_c(temp)
    (temp - 32).to_f * (5.0 / 9.0) 
  end
end
```

Comment: I just translated it to my actual context and it works great, thanks.  In terms of clarity, I think I don't quite understand what attr_writer is and does, and I need to wrestle with that some.  [This](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/50f0192b102455349200372d) will help, I think.  It definitely helps to see the correct implementation of what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: `Module#attr_writer` is a method which generates an attribute writer method. Its implementation looks (roughly) like this: `class Module; def attr_writer(*methods) methods.each do |method| define_method(:"#{method}=") do |val| instance_variable_set(:"@#{method}", val) end end end end`.